# xrandr output resolution not correct

Tags: ubuntu, resolution, xorg, xrandr

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04LTS on a pc with a hdmi and a vga connection, with integrated Intel Graphics (i3 processor).
I want to connect this pc to one TV (as information-dashboard).

The HDMI works without any issues (on Full HD resolution).

However the VGA display is not working as expected.

I want to set the resolution to 1360x768. I'm using xrandr for this with the following commands:

```
cvt 1368 768
```

This gives the output:

```
# 1368x768 59.88 Hz (CVT) hsync: 47.79 kHz; pclk: 85.25 MHz
Modeline "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
```

Then:

```
xrandr --newmode "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1368x768_60.00
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1368x768_60.00
```

When I run `xrandr -q` I get:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1360 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
VGA1 connected 1360x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1360x768       59.8  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   848x480        60.0  
   640x480        59.9  
   1360x768_60.00   59.8* 
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

However the OSD from my tv says is it 1024x768. And the content visible suggests the same.

If I do the same it with the resolution 1680x1050 it does work correctly.

The same TV connected to a Windows machine does display in 1360x768.

What am I missing / doing wrong?

Comment: Why did you add a new mode? 1360x768 is already in the list: what happens when you try and use this?

Comment: @AFH When I added the mode it got in there double. The same happens with the 1680x1050 resolution.

Comment: I am not sure I can help much with `xrandr`, as I use it for larger, virtual desktops: I have no experience of using it to change video mode. What I do use is **System Settings** -> **Screen Display**, and this appears to know which modes are supported. Have you tried this?

Comment: I don't use a desktop enviroment. Its just chrome running in nodm. All I can use to configure it is the cli (through ssh).